# Installing CUDA Toolkit for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, cuda, tensorflow

I need CUDA to develop a chatbot as described in this [tutorial](https://github.com/daniel-kukiela/nmt-chatbot). I'm trying to install CUDA using [these commands](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=runfilelocal).

Installer Type: Runfile(local). The first commands runs successfully but when I run the second one, it says

```
Installation failed. See log at /var/log/cuda-installer.log for details.
```

Are there any per-requisites that I should download before this? I have already installed tensorflow.

Comment: Hi did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your log file because this can help us in debugging this issue.Check using ls if the file is created or not.If not,you can use the .deb method mentioned beside the runfile method which usually works for ubuntu based systems.

Comment: I just checked. The cuda-installer.log file isn't present there. Why is that so? I believe I could download the .deb file but the requirements mentioned in the chatbot article say otherwise.

Comment: The .deb file should work for your case.can you send me a link for the chatbot article so i can check if the .deb method will work for you or not.

Comment: https://github.com/daniel-kukiela/nmt-chatbot @Dhruv

Comment: Hi.I checked the Link and if you install using the .deb file,you should be fine.Alternatively you can refer to this link https://medium.com/better-programming/install-tensorflow-1-13-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-gpu-support-239b36d29070 Which also includes installing CUDA.